# Add freq and place it in the graph

Tags: r

I am trying to get the variables of the freqs to add and put the total in the geom_bar.  Right now the male and female freqs of the HairEyeColor data show on top of each other- no adding.  Here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
hec = data.frame(HairEyeColor)
ggplot(hec, aes(Hair, Eye, fill=Freq)) + 
geom_bar(stat='identity',position= 'dodge') +
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
geom_text(aes(label=Freq),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),vjust=-0.25)
```

It is not adding the male and female frequency.  For example, there are 7 men and 7 women with red hair and green eyes.  It shows only 7- or more likely it's showing both 7's on top of each other.  That's why the brown /brown hair and eyes looks weird.  There are 53 men and 66 women with the brown/brown.

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It is not adding the values, because you program to use the values as is. You could remove the row sex and sum up the frequencies like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
hec = data.frame(HairEyeColor)

library(dplyr)

hec %<>%
  group_by(Hair, Eye) %>%
  summarise(Freq=sum(Freq))

ggplot(hec, aes(Hair, Eye, fill=Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position= 'dodge') +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_text(aes(label=Freq),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),vjust=-0.25)
```

Comment: I'm confused.  I don't have a row for sex.  when I run the code you gave it doesn't do anything.  Can you explain it like I'm five (EILIF)? please.  thanks.

Comment: I adjusted the code to a running and complete example. It should run and create the figure now.